# Specifying docker options for GitLab CI/CD

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I need to add the following options to run the Docker image. However I gave been unable to find from the documentation how one specifies these options in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
–device /dev/fuse --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --cap-add=MKNOD --security-opt apparmor:unconfined
```

Comment: Do you simply want to run a new container or want to execute the gitlab build inside a container, which has these options?

Comment: The image specified with 'image:my-docker/my-image:latest' in .gitlab-ci.yml needs to have these options - so I want to run all my CI jobs inside my-image

Comment: I think you need https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section See "The [runners.docker] section"

Comment: It works using the runner, but doesn't that mean that the CI pipeline now runs from my machine, not on the server that is hosting the GitLab? If so, then this undesirable, since if the connection to my personal computer is lost, then the runner won't run for others too? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, the runner can either be run on your computer or any server. You can install it where you want. It's not possible to configure this in the gitlab-ci.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those Docker options are not configured in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, they are specified in the runner's configuration found in the `config.toml` file.

The `[runners.docker]` [section](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) allows you to configure these options on a per-runner basis.

Here is an example of how to set those options:

```
[[runners]]
...
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "{your-image:tag}"
    cap_add = ["SYS_ADMIN", "MKNOD"]
    devices = ["/dev/fuse"]
    security_opt = ["apparmor:unconfined"]
    ...
```

Comment: I had the notion that when I run the CI with only the things specified in the .gitlab-ci.yml, the pipeline runs on that (private) server that is hosting the GitLab instance. Unfortunately I don't have the administrative rights for that server. Do I understand correctly that the runners should be registered in a different server than the one that is hosting the Gitlab? Since the server is used by a group of people, I wouldn't want that the runner is located on my personal machine (when computer is off, the pipeline can't run).

Comment: Runners can be hosted on separate servers, nearly anywhere.  You can register a if you have Owner permission to a group or project.